# Strange Intent filter pathPattern behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

[Documentation states](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path) that wildcards can be used in pathPattern.

> A period followed by an asterisk (".*") matches any sequence of 0 to many characters.

So, I've created the following filter:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="600">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>
    <data android:pathPattern="/.*.exe"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But, it does not "work" for all links which ends with ".exe".

Works for these links:

https://subdomain.site.org/lite/appinst-lite-vc.exe

https://subdomain.site.org/appinst.exe

Does NOT work for this link:

https://subdomain.freedownloadmanager.org/5/5.1-latest/app_x86_setup.exe

It seems, it's not working for links with extra dots in their `path` part.

Am I missing something or is it Android bug (either in code, or in documentation)?

P.S. This filter catches ALL these links:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="600">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>
    <data android:pathPattern="/.*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It's the `.` causing the problems.

Unlike in regular expression, in path pattern the matching will stop at the first match of the first character of the pattern. In other words, the * matching is non greedy.

One solution is adding multiple patters as below. The more you add, the more number or `.`s it can have without problems.

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.exe" />

<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.exe" />

<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..exe" />

<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.exe" />
```

Another solution is using [this](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch) library.

Answer (score 1):

Android uses `PatternMatcher` for this. And `.` symbol  has a special meaning in `PatternMatcher`. So, you have to use escape character `\`.

Try this :

```
<data android:pathPattern="/.*\.exe"/>
```

Also, since `\` is used as an escape character when the string is read from XML (before it is parsed as a pattern). So, you might need to double-escape it.

Like this :

```
<data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.exe"/>
```